# NEST ElasticSearch.Raw.IndiciesCreatePost does not get correct mappings for index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to use NEST to create an index with raw json and it produces different results than when I use that same json string interactively against elastic search.  Is this a bug or am I using it incorrectly?

Posting directly to elastic search with the following command I get exactly the mappings I want for my index (results shown below)

```
POST /entities
{
"mappings": {
  "sis_item" : 
  {
    "properties":
    {
      "FullPath":
      {
        "type": "string",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      },
      "Ident":
      {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties":
        {
          "ObjectGuid":
          {
              "type": "string",
              "index":"not_analyzed"
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }        
}
```

Result when I check the index with: GET /entities/ : (which is correct)

```
{
   "entities": {
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
     "sis_item": {
        "properties": {
           "FullPath": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "Ident": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                 "ObjectGuid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "settings": {
     "index": {
        "creation_date": "1453828294488",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "version": {
           "created": "1070499"
        },
        "uuid": "6_j4vRcqRwiTQw0E6bQokQ"
     }
  },
  "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

However I have to do this from code and using the following code the mappings I specify end up in the settings instead of the mappings as shown below.

```
                var createIndexJson = @"
                {
                    ""mappings"": {
                        ""sis_item"" :
                        {
                        ""properties"":
                        {
                            ""FullPath"":
                            {
                            ""type"": ""string"",
                            ""index"":""not_analyzed""
                            },
                            ""Ident"":
                            {
                            ""type"": ""nested"",
                            ""properties"":
                            {
                                ""ObjectGuid"":
                                {
                                    ""type"": ""string"",
                                    ""index"":""not_analyzed""
                                }
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }";

var response = _client.Raw.IndicesCreatePost("entities_from_code", createIndexJson);
if (!response.Success || response.HttpStatusCode != 200)
{
  throw new ElasticsearchServerException(response.ServerError);
}
```

Result (not correct, notice the mappings are nested inside the settings):

```
{
 "entities_from_code": {
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {},
  "settings": {
     "index": {
        "mappings": {
           "sis_item": {
              "properties": {
                 "FullPath": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 },
                 "Ident": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                       "ObjectGuid": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        "creation_date": "1453828283162",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "version": {
           "created": "1070499"
        },
        "uuid": "fdmPqahGToCJw_mIbq0kNw"
     }
  },
  "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

Comment: Works great with the latest version of NEST(2.0.0-alpha2) - just in case you would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newline at the very top of the json string which cause the odd result, removing it gave me the expected behaviour.